# UITableView delay reloadData until animation complete

Tags: ios, uitableview, animation, reloaddata

I've got a UITableView that represents a checklist of items. Each item is in a done/undone state.

I'd like to keep all of the done items at the top of the list, so when the user clicks an item that is undone, I'd like to figure out where the row should go (at end of currently-done items list) and move it there.

I'm trying to use `-moveRowAtIndexPath:toIndexPath:` for my UITableView to do this.

It works well sometimes and not so well at other times.

It seems to work well when the done action kicks off another animation elsewhere on screen. For some reason, this seems to serve as a delay for the `-reloadData` call.

When that's not true (i.e., the only thing "happening" is the row being marked done and moving), the animation seems to get short-circuited by an automatic call to the UITableView's `-reloadData` method. That is, the animation begins, but about halfway through, `-reloadData` is called and the rows snap to their final position. It's fairly jarring from the user's perspective.

I've tracked through my code to verify that I'm not calling `-reloadData` myself, and it doesn't appear that I'm the one triggering this `-reloadData` call.

I'm OK with the automatic call to `-reloadData` and I understand why it's called (though you'd think it might not be necessary, but that's a different issue), but I'd really like it to wait until it completes its animation.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
NSIndexPath *oldPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:currentIndex inSection:0];
NSIndexPath *newPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:newIndex     inSection:0];

[tableView beginUpdates];

[checklist removeObject:task];
[checklist insertObject:task atIndex:newIndex];
[tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:oldPath toIndexPath:newPath];

[tableView endUpdates];
```

Am I screwing something up?

Comment: Doh! I really WAS calling `-reloadData` manually. It was just subtle and from a timer, which wasn't being reached with breakpoints enabled. Doh! Doh! Doh! ;-)

Comment: Please add your solution as an answer to this question and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the request of titaniumdecoy, here's how I got this issue fixed:

I have a `UIViewController` subclass with an `NSTimer` that executes once a second, checking the underlying data source for a `UITableView` for changes that indicate a call to `-reloadData` is necessary. So, to that subclass I added:

```
@property (BOOL) IsAnimating;
```

I set this initially to `NO` and if the `isAnimating` property is set to `YES`, the `NSTimer` "short-circuits" and skips its normal processing.

So, when I want to run this `UITableView` animation, I set the `isAnimating` property to `YES` and run the animation.

Then, I schedule a selector to run 1 second in the future that will reset `isAnimating` to `NO`. The `NSTimer` will then continue firing and will see an `isAnimating` of `NO` (most likely on the second subsequent call to `-codeTimerFired`) and then find the data source update, kicking off a call to `reloadData`.

Here's the code for suspending the `NSTimer`'s processing and scheduling the `UITableView` animation:

```
// currentIndex and newIndex have already been calculated as the data item's
// original and destination indices (only 1 section in UITableView)
if (currentIndex != newIndex) {

    // This item's index has changed, so animate its movement
    NSIndexPath *oldPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:currentIndex    inSection:0];
    NSIndexPath *newPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:newIndex        inSection:0];

    // Set a flag to disable data source processing and calls to [UITableView reloadData] 
    [[self Owner] setIsAnimating:YES];

    // I haven't tested enough, but some documentation leads me to believe
    // that this particular call (-moveRowAtIndexPath:toIndexPath:) may NOT need
    // to be wrapped in a -beginUpdates/-endUpdates block
    [[[self Owner] InstructionsTableView] beginUpdates];

    // These lines move the item in my data source
    [[[MMAppDelegate singleton] CurrentChecklist] removeObject:[self CellTask]];
    [[[MMAppDelegate singleton] CurrentChecklist] insertObject:[self CellTask] atIndex:newIndex];

    // This code is the UITableView animation
    [[[self Owner] InstructionsTableView] moveRowAtIndexPath:oldPath toIndexPath:newPath];

    // Conclude the UITableView animation block
    [[[self Owner] InstructionsTableView] endUpdates];

    // Schedule a call to re-enable UITableView animation        
    [[self Owner] performSelector:@selector(setIsAnimating:) withObject:@(NO) afterDelay:1.0];

} else {
    // This location hasn't changed, so just tell my owner to reload its data
    [[[self Owner] InstructionsTableView] reloadData];
}
```

Here's the `NSTimer` method (note how it bails out if `isAnimating == YES`):

```
- (void)codeTimerFired {

    // This is a subclass of a template subclass... 
    // super actually has work to do in this method...
    [super codeTimerFired];

    // If we're in the middle of an animation, don't update!
    if ([self IsAnimating]) {
        return;
    }

    // Other data source processing...

    // local BOOL to check whether underlying data source has changed
    BOOL shouldUpdate = NO;

    // code to check if underlying data source has changed...
    // ******************************************************
    // [CODE REMOVED]
    // ******************************************************

    // If the underlying data source has changed, update the UITableView
    if (shouldUpdate) {
        [self reloadTableView]; // <--- This is the main line I wanted to prevent
                                //      since the code that fired to cause the 
                                //      UITableView animation will ALWAYS cause
                                //      the underlying data source to change such
                                //      that this line would fire.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Swift**

```
//---------
extension UITableView {

    // Default delay time = 0.5 seconds
    // Pass animation time interval, as a parameter argument
    func reloadDataAfterDelay(delayTime: TimeInterval = 0.5) -> Void {
        self.perform(#selector(self.reloadData), with: nil, afterDelay: delayTime)
    }

}
```